# Приведение БД к 3НФ

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть база данных организации. В ней есть таблицы `Отделы`, `Подотделы` и `Сотрудники`.

В таблице `Подотделы` есть внешний ключ на отдел, которому принадлежит подотдет.

Правильно ли я понимаю, чтобы БД соответствовала 3НФ, в таблице `Сотрудники` должен быть внешний ключ только на подотдел, которому принадлежит сотрудник?

Если же в табилице `Сотрудники` будут поля с внешними ключами на отдел и подотдел, то это уже будет не 3НФ, т. к. подотдел зависит от отдела?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете. нужна только одна ссылка на подотдел

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575788/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-4-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/575847#575847

Answer (score 1):

Для проектирования БД есть особые стандарты, например `IDEF1X`.

Следуя этому стандарту многие вопросы отпадают сами собой, а на выходе вы получаете 3НФ.

Для следования этому стандарту есть даже специальный софт, например Toad Data Modeler.